# Can I unstring a literal in a macro?

Tags: rust

I want to make a macro that does this

```
mac1!("foo", x)
```

emits

```
foo(x)
```

is it even possible?

Comment: Yes it most certainly is possible. Out of curiosity why does the macro take a string input? Why not just an identifier?

Comment: Macros by example cannot mint new identifiers like this, but a procedural macro could.

Comment: @PiRocks cos I have a big (100 lines) match that today has dbg1("x") on each match. And I wanted to redefine dbg1 to be a fn call. Can I do it the other way round foo => "foo". Its a skeleton, I need to invoke the match and make it do different things with what i decodes depending on where I use it

Comment: [`stringify`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html) will perform the reverse.

Comment: @eggyal - ty for yr help, it would be too complicated to go into in comments. I will work it out - ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. By the time the macro is expanded, the matching is done on the fact that `"foo"` is an `expression` (or a `literal`). The compiler does not distinguish between an expression like `"foo"` in your example and `123u8`, `1 + 2`, `foo()` or `{ let f = fs::read("foo.txt"); ... }` as all of those are expressions. All the macro-by-example knows is that the first parameter is any kind of valid expression and it can't look deeper into it, because the compiler doesn't know what a "type" or a "value" is at this point.

You can use a procedural macro, which *can* use a parameter's value to generate new tokens, including identifiers.